# I tried to allocate memory using malloc in a structure but it didn't work?Why?

Tags: c, malloc

```
## Code to read general information ##
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>    
typedef struct{
    char *name =(char*)malloc(20);
    int age;
    int id;
}info;
main()
{
    info a;
    printf("Enter Name :");
    scanf(" %[^\n]",a.name);
    a.age=19;
    a.id=11700055;
    printf("Name :%s\nAge :%d\nId :%d\nSize of info 
:%d\n",a.name,a.age,a.id,sizeof(a));
    return 0;
}




  https://i.stack.imgur.com/WoA0T.png
```

what is wrong with this code?
    it's showing errors i don't understand like info has no member named 'name'?

it also says that name,age,id are not the members of info.

Comment: what error is it showing?

Comment: Because you are merely defining the type of the struct.  You can allocate memory to the pointer in the struct when you have actual instance of the struct to work with.

Comment: @coderredoc there is a link at bottom for errors

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code & output, copy & paste the output in your question.

Answer (score 4):

Inside struct declaration you are allocating memory that is not allowed.

If you need array inside of it

```
typedef struct{
    char name[20];
    int age;
    int id;
}info;
```

Alternatively you can do this

```
#define MAXLEN 20

    typedef struct{
        char* name;
        int age;
        int id;
    }info;

info p;
p.name = malloc(MAXLEN);
if(!p.name){ perror("malloc");exit(1);}
...
```

It should be `int main(void)` not `main()`.

Comment: Okay. But it other program when i allocated memory it worked.

Comment: @KaranBishwakarma.: **No it won't**.

Comment: why it's showing errors like info has no members named name,age, and id?

Comment: @KaranBishwakarma.: Because the malloc line was an error..compiler couldn't find the declaration of the `id`,`name` age etc. The struct declaratio was not succesful.

Comment: @Karan - If you compile the code as C++ you might be able to have default values for struct members, but not in C.